# Search box, can not click on result 'a' element

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, hyperlink, jquery-events

I made an search box that use ajax like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.search-box input[type="search"]').on("keyup", function() {
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $("div.dropdown-menu");

        if( inputVal.length) {
            $.get("/ajax/search/users", {term: inputVal} ).done( function( data ) {
                resultDropdown.empty();
                const users = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

               users.forEach(element => {
                    $slug = element['slug'];

                    resultDropdown.append("<a class='dropdown-item' href='/" + $slug + "'></a>")
               });

               resultDropdown.dropdown('toggle');
            });
        } else {
            resultDropdown.empty();
            resultDropdown.removeClass('show');
        }
    });
});
```

but when I try to 'click' on my 'a' that doesn't change my `windows.location` to the href.

```
<div class="dropdown show">
     <div class="dropdown-menu overflow-auto show" aria-expanded="true">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounttest-1"></a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounttest-2"></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the hyperlinks have nothing to `click` - ie: nothing between `<a href='/acctest-1'>NOTHING HERE</a>`

Comment: Same problem if i add something between 'a'

Comment: It seems that when i add an 'a' element with js after the page load, this 'a 'element can't open directly the href link when user click on him

Comment: For provisional solution i make : aDom.attr('onclick', "window.location.href='/"+slug+"'")